# Find the triple integral using reasoning, not iterated integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The solid region E that is the right circular cone of height $10$ and diameter
$5$, sitting with its base on the $xy$-plane centered at $(0,0,0)$.

Use reasoning to compute the following triple integral without converting it into iterated integrals.

$$\iiint_E x+ydV$$

I am not sure how to begin this problem without using iterated integrals? I graphed the cone using Mathemtica as well as the graph of $z=x+y$.

Comment: Have you studied mass, center of mass and etc.?  And I think the cone's base's center should be $\;(0,0,0)\;$ , as you're working in the space $\;\Bbb R^3\;$ .

Comment: yes i have but this does not seem to be a mass related problem

Comment: Well, Joriki's answer already solved...and without using any physics.

Answer (score 1):

The cone is symmetric with respect to inversion of any axis lying in the $xy$-plane, in particular the $x$ and $y$ axis. Thus the integral is zero by symmetry.

Comment: what do you mean by inversion of any axis in the xy-plane? it makes sense to me that the integral would be zero, however, i am not sure I understand how to explain it

Comment: @BennettLerud: Sorry, I forgot to answer this question. I mean that if you choose any axis in the $xy$ plane, and in particular the $x$ axis or the $y$ axis, and invert the coordinate along that axis (i.e. apply a reflection in the plane through the origin that's perpendicular to that axis), the cone remains invariant. Hence the integral over $x$ is equal to the integral over $-x$, and hence is zero; and likewise for $y$.